# How to tell if tensorflow is using gpu acceleration from inside python shell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, cuda, gpu

I have installed tensorflow in my ubuntu 16.04 using the second answer [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/936429/-solved-tensorflow-with-gpu-in-anaconda-env-ubuntu-16-04-cuda-7-5-cudnn-/) with ubuntu's builtin apt cuda installation.

Now my question is how can I test if tensorflow is really using gpu? I have a gtx 960m gpu. When I `import tensorflow` this is the output

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

Is this output enough to check if tensorflow is using gpu ?

Comment: You should see something like this in your log: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:838] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)

Comment: There's `log_device_placement` approach in answer. The most reliable way is to look at timeline as specified in this comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659

Comment: Yes , I have got this output following Yao Zhang's answer...

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov in what log? Does it write it to a file or where do I check if a statement like that appears?

Comment: It writes to stdout or stderr

Comment: if you don't want to go to the python shell you can do it on unix by just checking `nvidia-smi` and seeing if ur script is running.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov , I got this in my log. But I didn't get the output that is shown by Tamim when he does `import tensorflow`. Should i consider that my tensorflow is using Cuda or not?

Comment: `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

Answer (score 447, accepted):

No, I don't think "open CUDA library" is enough to tell, because different nodes of the graph may be on different devices.

When using tensorflow2:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

For tensorflow1, to find out which device is used, you can enable log device placement like this:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Check your console for this type of output.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it prints absolutely nothing. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Did you do it on a jupyter notebook ?

Comment: Same as @Qubix, it doesn't print anything. I'm executing it in a Jupyter notebook. I tried to print sess but I got nothing relevant.

Comment: The output may be produced on the console from where you ran the Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Qubix and  richar8086, it prints on the terminal where you started jupyter notebook

Comment: It printed 2018-02-10 05:21:06.855163: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
Device mapping: no known devices.
2018-02-10 05:21:06.856681: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping .   is it GPU enabled

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: Gee whiz. You'd think this would be a simpler query.

Comment: can anybody answer me why `device 0` mapping information appeared twice? why this is caused.

Comment: Does this have to be for Ubuntu to work? I am using a windows device. I have noticed that when run Tensorflow that the GPU is churning hard, but whenever I run this command I do not show any results

Comment: @Cameron That seems weird. It works on my computer (windows). You have tensorflow-gpu, right?

Comment: Can we get an updated answer for Tensorflow V2 (where tf.Sessions are not supported).

Comment: @iyop45
For tensorflow V2, the command is a bit modified: `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

Comment: @musically jupyter/ipython is not the only way. You can also run it from console with `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))"` Just a note: the gpu variant is included in the main import for some time now.

Comment: The print ignores XLA_GPUs

Answer (score 302):

Apart from using `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))` which is outlined in other answers as well as in the official TensorFlow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu), you can try to assign a computation to the gpu and see whether you have an error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

Here

- "/cpu:0": The CPU of your machine.
- "/gpu:0": The GPU of your machine, if you have one.

If you have a gpu and can use it, you will see the result. Otherwise you will see an error with a long stacktrace. In the end you will have something like this:

> Cannot assign a device to node 'MatMul': Could not satisfy explicit
>   device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that
>   specification are registered in this process

---

Recently a few helpful functions appeared in TF:

- [tf.test.is_gpu_available](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available) tells if the gpu is available
- [tf.test.gpu_device_name](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/gpu_device_name) returns the name of the gpu device

You can also check for available devices in the session:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  devices = sess.list_devices()
```

`devices` will return you something like

```
[_DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, -1, 4670268618893924978),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 6127825144471676437),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0, XLA_GPU, 17179869184, 16148453971365832732),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 17179869184, 10003582050679337480),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 17179869184, 5678397037036584928)
```

Comment: Result:[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]

Comment: @GeorgePligor the result is not really important here. Either you have a result and the GPU was used or you have an error, which means that it was not used

Comment: This did not work for me. I ran this inside of my Docker Container that is exectued by the nvidia-docker and etcetc. However I get no error and the CPU is the one that does the work. I upped the matrices a bit (10k*10k) to ensure it calculates for a while. CPU util went up to 100% but the GPU stayed cool as always.

Comment: I got the "no devices matching" error when run it in console. In IDE like pycharm there is no error. I guess it's related to the Session I used, which is different in console.

Comment: Easy to understand. If GPU available it will print something like `Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Practical solutions.

Comment: if you're using a newer version of tf, you'll need something like `with tf.device('/device:XLA_GPU:0')`  instead

Comment: dosen't seem to work for tensorflow 2.1 at all, even after replacing `Session` with `tf.compat.v1.Session()`

Comment: 2020-06-12 01:13:11.514723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:54] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0                                                                           
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]]

Comment: tf.test.is_gpu_available() seems to test a GPU computation, and as hard as it is to accept the result `False` (after many attempts to install), it was correct for me. Side note: From my experiences, it's easier to install a TF 2.x version with GPU support and upgrade the deprecated usages of 1.x, than to getting a 1.x install with GPU to work.

Comment: `tf.test.is_gpu_available` is deprecated. Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.

Answer (score 207):

Following piece of code should give you all devices available to tensorflow.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

> Sample Output
>
> [name: "/cpu:0"
>   device_type: "CPU"
>   memory_limit: 268435456
>   locality {
>   }
>   incarnation: 4402277519343584096,
>
> name: "/gpu:0"
>   device_type: "GPU"
>   memory_limit: 6772842168
>   locality {
>     bus_id: 1
>   }
>   incarnation: 7471795903849088328
>   physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0"
>   ]

Comment: and if this command does not return any entry with "GPU", does it mean my machine simply does have GPU, or tensorflow is not able to locate it?

Comment: @mercury0114 it may be either. for example, you may have a gpu but not have tensorflow-gpu properly installed.

Comment: I disagree, this does **not** answer the question: it's not about devices _available_ but devises **used**. And that can be an entirely different story! (e.g. TF will only use 1 GPU by default.

Comment: name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 10711446324
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {  }}
incarnation: 17935632445266485019
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"]

Answer (score 139):

**Tensorflow 2.0**

Sessions are no longer used in 2.0. Instead, one can use [`tf.test.is_gpu_available`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available):

```
import tensorflow as tf

assert tf.test.is_gpu_available()
assert tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

If you get an error, you need to check your installation.

Comment: That also works with TF 1.14 (maybe even a few older versions)!

Comment: It is now recommended to do `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

Comment: @Roy Shilkrot I think 'tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')' doesn't work in Tensorflow 2.0

Comment: @joselquin The TF v2.x docs state it should work: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/list_physical_devices , and I can verify it does work for me.

Answer (score 124):

I think there is an easier way to achieve this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

It usually prints like

```
Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0
```

This seems easier to me rather than those verbose logs.

Edit:-
This was tested for TF 1.x versions. I never had a chance to do stuff with TF 2.0 or above so keep in mind.

Comment: Agreed. Easier than the approaches described above. Prints the list of GPUs its using. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a valid test.  It will return into the else statement even if you have the GPU version of tensorflow installed.

Comment: Works for me of tf-1.14 and two GPU inside.

Answer (score 39):

**UPDATE FOR TENSORFLOW >= 2.1**

The recommended way in which to check if TensorFlow is using GPU is the following:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

As of TensorFlow 2.1, `tf.test.gpu_device_name()` has been deprecated in favour of the aforementioned.

Then, in the terminal you can use `nvidia-smi` to check how much GPU memory has been alloted; at the same time, using `watch -n K nvidia-smi` would tell you for example every K seconds how much memory you are using (you may want to use `K = 1` for real-time)

If you have multiple GPUs and you want to use multiple networks, each one on a separated GPU, you can use:

```
 with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
      neural_network_1 = initialize_network_1()
 with tf.device('/GPU:1'):
      neural_network_2 = initialize_network_2()
```

Comment: To see constantly how much GPU memory using , use `nvidia-smi -l 10`.

Answer (score 32):

Ok, first launch an `ipython shell` from the terminal and `import` TensorFlow:

```
$ ipython --pylab
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
```

Now, we can *watch* the GPU memory usage in a console using the following command:

```
# realtime update for every 2s
$ watch -n 2 nvidia-smi
```

Since we've only `import`ed TensorFlow but have not used any GPU yet, the usage stats will be:

[image: tf non-gpu usage]

Notice how the GPU memory usage is very less (~ 700MB); Sometimes the GPU memory usage might even be as low as 0 MB.

---

Now, let's load the GPU in our code. As indicated in [`tf documentation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu), do:

```
In [2]: sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Now, the *watch* stats should show an updated GPU usage memory as below:

[image: tf gpu-watch]

Observe now how our Python process from the ipython shell is using ~ 7 GB of the GPU memory.

---

P.S. You can continue *watching* these stats as the code is running, to see how intense the GPU usage is over time.

Answer (score 30):

This will confirm that tensorflow using GPU while training also ?

*Code*

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

*Output*

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 730
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9015
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 1.98GiB
Free memory: 1.72GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:255] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GT 730, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation to _why_ your answer is working (what does the `log_device_placement` do and how to see CPU vs. GPU in the output?). That will improve the quality of your answer!

Answer (score 30):

In addition to other answers, the following should help you to make sure that your version of tensorflow includes GPU support.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

Comment: Warning: That tells you if TensorFlow is compiled with GPU. Not whether the GPU is being used. (If the drivers are not installed properly for example, then the CPU is used, even if "is_built_with_cuda()" is true.)

Answer (score 19):

This should give the list of devices available for Tensorflow (under Py-3.6):

```
tf = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
tf.list_devices()
# _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 268435456)
```

Answer (score 14):

I prefer to use nvidia-smi to monitor GPU usage. if it goes up significantly when you start you program, it's a strong sign that your tensorflow is using GPU.

Comment: This is an indirect way

Comment: How do you use nvdia-smi to monitor GPU usage?

Comment: after you install cuda. nvidia-smi should be in your system. I usually use 'nvidia-smi -l ' to monitor the usage.

Comment: You can also use watch nvidia-smi, updates the screen every 2 seconds

Comment: watch nvidia-smi works well for me. I can also see in the output that my python process is using the GPU

Answer (score 9):

I find just querying the gpu from the command line is easiest:

```
nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.98                 Driver Version: 384.98                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 22%   33C    P8    13W / 250W |   5817MiB /  6075MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1060      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            53MiB |
|    0     25177      C   python                                      5751MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

if your learning is a background process the pid from 
`jobs -p` should match the pid from `nvidia-smi`

Answer (score 9):

With the recent updates of Tensorflow, you can check it as follow :

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available( cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
```

This will return `True` if GPU is being used by `Tensorflow`, and return `False` otherwise.

If you want device `device_name` you can type : `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`.
Get more details from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test)

Answer (score 9):

With tensorflow 2.0 >=

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Run the following in Jupyter,

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

If you've set up your environment properly, you'll get the following **output in the terminal where you ran "jupyter notebook"**,

```
2017-10-05 14:51:46.335323: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro K620, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro K620, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0
2017-10-05 14:51:46.337418: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:265] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Quadro K620, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0
```

You can see here I'm using TensorFlow with an Nvidia Quodro K620.

Comment: Jupyter is not necessary at all, please don't add complexity to the question

Comment: Some users may want to ensure GPU is usable in Jupyter. Additionally, this can be run from a Python script.

Answer (score 8):

#### For TF2.4+ listed as the "official" way on [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) to check if TF is using GPU or Not

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
Num GPUs Available:  2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can check if you are currently using the GPU by running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

If the output is `''`, it means you are using `CPU` only;
If the output is something like that `/device:GPU:0`, it means `GPU` works.

---

And use the following code to check which `GPU` you are using:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Comment: If the output is `' '`, then what should we do?

Comment: @Jason Just reinstall a GPU version.

Answer (score 6):

Put this near the top of your jupyter notebook.  Comment out what you don't need.

```
# confirm TensorFlow sees the GPU
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
assert 'GPU' in str(device_lib.list_local_devices())

# confirm Keras sees the GPU (for TensorFlow 1.X + Keras)
from keras import backend
assert len(backend.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()) > 0

# confirm PyTorch sees the GPU
from torch import cuda
assert cuda.is_available()
assert cuda.device_count() > 0
print(cuda.get_device_name(cuda.current_device()))
```

---

**NOTE:** With the release of TensorFlow 2.0, Keras is now included as part of the TF API.

Originally answerwed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53244520/420400).

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf 
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

2020-05-10 14:58:16.243814: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-05-10 14:58:16.262675: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-10 14:58:16.263119: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7715GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 5.93GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-05-10 14:58:16.263143: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-10 14:58:16.263188: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-10 14:58:16.264289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-10 14:58:16.264495: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-10 14:58:16.265644: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-10 14:58:16.266329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-10 14:58:16.266357: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-10 14:58:16.266478: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-10 14:58:16.266823: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-10 14:58:16.267107: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

As suggested by @AmitaiIrron:

This section indicates that a gpu was found

```
2020-05-10 14:58:16.263119: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:

pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7715GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 5.93GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
```

And here that it got added as an available physical device

```
2020-05-10 14:58:16.267107: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Comment: It would be useful if you point to the sections in the output that indicate whether a GPU is used.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron Thanks for the suggestion, i hope it is a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 6):

In the new versions of TF(>2.1) the recommended way for checking whether TF is using GPU is:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Answer (score 5):

The following will also return the name of your GPU devices.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

Comment: If the output of this command is an empty string ... how I do debug?

Answer (score 5):

I found below snippet is very handy to test the gpu ..

#### Tensorflow 2.0 Test

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

#### Tensorflow 1 Test

```py
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 5):

#### For Tensorflow 2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False,
    min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)
```

source [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available?version=stable)

other option is:

```
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Comment: `is_gpu_available` (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score 5):

## Tensorflow 2.1

A simple calculation that can be verified with nvidia-smi for memory usage on the GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

c1 = []
n = 10

def matpow(M, n):
    if n < 1: #Abstract cases where n < 1
        return M
    else:
        return tf.matmul(M, matpow(M, n-1))

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=(10000, 10000)), name="a")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=(10000, 10000)), name="b")
    c1.append(matpow(a, n))
    c1.append(matpow(b, n))
```

Comment: A nice test not only to check if tensorflow sees the GPU but if it will actually use one.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command in Jupyter or your IDE to check if Tensorflow is using a GPU or not: `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

Answer (score 3):

This is the line I am using to list devices available to `tf.session` directly from bash:

```
python -c "import os; os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'; import tensorflow as tf; sess = tf.Session(); [print(x) for x in sess.list_devices()]; print(tf.__version__);"
```

It will print available devices and tensorflow version, for example:

```
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 268435456, 10588614393916958794)
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0, XLA_GPU, 17179869184, 12320120782636586575)
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 13378821206986992411)
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0, GPU, 32039954023, 12481654498215526877)
1.14.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some options to test whether GPU acceleration is being used by your TensorFlow installation.

You can type in the following commands in three different platforms.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

1. Jupyter Notebook - Check the console which is running the Jupyter Notebook. You will be able to see the GPU being used.
2. Python Shell - You will be able to directly see the output. (Note- do not assign the output of the second command to the variable 'sess'; if that helps).
3. Spyder - Type in the following command in the console.

   `import tensorflow as tf
   tf.test.is_gpu_available()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TensorFlow 2.0, you can use this for loop to show the devices:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  devices = sess.list_devices()
devices
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using tensorflow 2.x use:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the most simple and comprehensive approach. Just set `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` and you should see if ops are actually run on GPU e.g. `Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0`

More in the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#logging_device_placement

Comment: That  solution is great

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this:

python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

to see if the system returns the tensor

according to [the site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#virtual-environment-install)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1-liner from command line:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```