# How to check if keras tensorflow backend is GPU or CPU version?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I understand that when installing tensorflow, you either install the GPU or CPU version. How can I check which one is installed (I use linux).

If the GPU version is installed, would it be automatically running on CPU if GPU is unavailable or would it throw an error? And if GPU is available, is there a specific field or value you need to set to make sure it's running on GPU?

Comment: @SalvadorDali I have tried the answers to that question, but it does not print out anything. Also, it does not answer my question: If the GPU version is installed, would it be automatically running on CPU if GPU is unavailable or would it throw an error? And if GPU is available, is there a specific field or value you need to set to make sure it's running on GPU?

Comment: *but it does not print out anything* how is it possible? Have you tried my answer there. It is either printing something or failing and the answer explain what each of these steps mean. Basically 2 of the questions you just asked here in the comments are answered there

Comment: @SalvadorDali, Apologies. I tried your code, it works and it shows that it's running on CPU. However, how can I check if the tensorflow I have is GPU version or CPU version?

Answer (score 77):

Also you can check using Keras backend function:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

I test this on Keras (2.1.1)

Comment: Running from a command line session on Ubuntu 16.04 this works, but then it doesn't prompt for other commands, same with directly tensorflow, and then O'd have to restart the terminal. Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: What should be the output of above command

Comment: @Nitin It should give you a list of available GPUs on your machine.  For instance on mine I get: `['/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0']`

Comment: does not work in TF 2.0

Comment: ```AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 from keras import backend as K
----> 2 K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()

...\tensorflow_backend.py in _get_available_gpus()
    504             _LOCAL_DEVICES = [x.name for x in devices]
    505         else:
--> 506             _LOCAL_DEVICES = tf.config.experimental_list_devices()
    507     return [x for x in _LOCAL_DEVICES if 'device:gpu' in x.lower()]
    508 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices'```

Comment: for **TF 2.0**:
`from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K`
@ShitalShah

Comment: Adding to the above comment, for TF 2.0,
`from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K` followed by `K._get_available_gpus()`.

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'tensorflow_backend'

Comment: @AnirudhAjith does the availability of a GPU guarantee that it's in use?

Answer (score 30):

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-keras-on-gpu).

> If you are running on the TensorFlow or CNTK backends, your code will automatically run on GPU if any available GPU is detected.

You can check what all devices are used by tensorflow by -

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Also as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell)

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

This will print whether your tensorflow is using a CPU or a GPU backend. If you are running this command in jupyter notebook, check out the console from where you have launched the notebook.

If you are sceptic whether you have installed the tensorflow gpu version or not. You can install the gpu version via pip.

`pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: i have tensorflow gpu installed, but keras doesn't pick it, what to do?

Comment: Did you follow the official guide - https://keras.io/backend/ ?

Comment: If you have tensorflow-gpu installed but Keras isn't picking it up, then it's likely that the CUDA libraries aren't being found. You need the CUDA lib paths and bin path (for ptxas) to use GPU with Keras/TF effectively.