# Keras backend and tensorflow showing conflicting GPU devices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I know there have been [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068243/how-to-check-if-keras-tensorflow-backend-is-gpu-or-cpu-version) different [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544766/how-do-i-check-if-keras-is-using-gpu-version-of-tensorflow) regarding this matter, but it seems every time a new keras / tensorflow version is released, there's conflict with package versions and inevtibly the version I have doesn't use my GPU.

I have a single conda environment where I have installed all my packages (there is nothing in the `base` environment to avoid package conflict)

Packages:

- keras 2.3.1
- tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0

and no other tensorflow / keras versions (although I do have related packages like `keras-applications` and `tensorboard`).

When I try the following, I get conflicting results

```
# picks up the GPU it seems
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
>>> [name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4346857393168915334
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 15716071101553989809
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 6257014534476475142
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]

# but then Keras doesn't pick up the GPU?
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
>>> []
```

So tensorflow seems to pick up the GPU, but then Keras doesn't? This doesn't make sense, as Keras is using Tensorflow backend.

Am I doing something wrong here? Why is TF picking up the GPU but Keras isn't? Will Keras still use the GPU even though the `_get_available_gpus()` method returns an empty list?

Comment: Did you try `from tf.keras import backend as K`?

Comment: What problem do you have that it led you to import stuff directly from tensorflow_backend? That makes no sense, if tensorflow detects your GPU, so will Keras, don't mess with the internals of Keras.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It seems I am getting this error: `E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:238] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`