# Can I run Keras model on gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

I'm running a Keras model, with a submission deadline of 36 hours, if I train my model on the cpu it will take approx 50 hours, is there a way to run Keras on gpu?

I'm using Tensorflow backend and running it on my Jupyter notebook, without anaconda installed.

Comment: I found this: https://medium.com/@kegui/how-do-i-know-i-am-running-keras-model-on-gpu-a9cdcc24f986  It feels like one could peruse highly rated questions in a narrow field here, and then make a full "answer" on Medium, and make actual money from views.

Comment: For AMD GPU. See this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016869/6117565

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Yes you can run keras models on GPU. Few things you will have to check first.

1. your system has GPU (Nvidia. As AMD doesn't work yet)
2. You have installed the GPU version of tensorflow
3. You have installed CUDA [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)
4. Verify that tensorflow is running with GPU [check if GPU is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell)

`sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

for TF > v2.0

`sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

(Thanks @nbro and @Ferro for pointing this out in the comments)

OR

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

output will be something like this:

```
[
  name: "/cpu:0"device_type: "CPU",
  name: "/gpu:0"device_type: "GPU"
]
```

Once all this is done your model will run on GPU:

To Check if keras(>=2.1.1) is using GPU:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

All the best.

Comment: i will have to install python 3.5 for this right?else tensorflow will not work?

Comment: Not necessary. TF works with 2.7 and 3.5 both. Chose the correct version of TF that's it.

Comment: alright ,ill go with 2.7,havig issues with installing 3.5

Comment: I get this Error  -`Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /home/hyperworks/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: any idea? i get this when i try to upgrade tensorflow

Comment: Did you try `pip install tensorflow` ?? That should install tensorflow without any issues.

Comment: you can use `device_lib`. I have shared the code in answer.

Comment: what does "enable GPU mean"? Is there concrete code to write so that it DOES run on GPU for sure?

Comment: I happen to have both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu installed in this particular anaconda environment... when I run the python above it doesn't say that I have any gpus available.  If I run the keras.backend, it says keras.backend.tensorflow_backend has no attribute _get_available_gpus ...

Comment: Note that [Anaconda](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc?source=post_actions_footer-----52e5249374bc---------------------clap_footer-&gi=5a1d157af41f) sounds quite easy for installing tensorflow with gpu support

Comment: @VikashSingh, I followed the instruction as mentioned. But still my Keras model running on CPU, because the GPU consumption is 0 whereas CPU consumption reached to 30%. When Im running tensorflow model, by default logs says its running on GPU. Not sure where exactly Im wrong. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: `K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()` does not work in TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: The first line of code gives an error for tf V2. This line works:
`sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

Comment: It is implied that if there is a GPU available, operations will be mapped to it. Is that right? In that case, how could one chose the CPU even if GPU is available?

Answer (score 26):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: While above mentioned answer explain in detail on how to use GPU on Keras Model, I want to explain how it can be done for `Tensorflow Version 2.0`.

To know how many GPUs are available, we can use the below code:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

To find out which devices your operations and tensors are assigned to, 
put `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` as the first statement of your program.

Enabling device placement logging causes any Tensor allocations or operations to be printed. For example, running the below code:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

gives the Output shown below:

> Executing op MatMul in device
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 tf.Tensor( [[22. 28.] 
>   [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)

For more information, refer [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

Comment: There are now XLA_GPU that are not showns if I list only 'GPU'. Maybe that is also the reason keras doesn't seem to see my gpu

Answer (score 24):

Sure. I suppose that you have already installed TensorFlow for GPU.

You need to add the following block after importing keras. I am working on a machine which have 56 core cpu, and a gpu.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf


config = tf.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 1 , 'CPU': 56} ) 
sess = tf.Session(config=config) 
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

Of course, this usage enforces my machines maximum limits. You can decrease cpu and gpu consumption values.

Comment: Error `module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'`

Comment: You are using tensorflow 2? I tested it for tf 1.X.

Comment: the only answer which actually tells that running keras on gpu requires installing whole another stack of software, starting from nvidia driver to '-gpu' build of the keras itself, plus minding cudnn and cuda proper installation and linking

Comment: For tf2.x
import keras
import tensorflow as tf


config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 1 , 'CPU': 8} ) 
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) 
keras.backend.set_session(sess)

Answer (score 2):

Of course. if you are running on Tensorflow or CNTk backends, your code will run on your GPU devices defaultly.But if Theano backends, you can use following

> Theano flags:
>
> > "THEANO_FLAGS=device=gpu,floatX=float32 python my_keras_script.py"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Anaconda on Windows 10, with a GTX 1660 Super. I first installed the CUDA environment following this [step-by-step](https://medium.com/@medasuryatej/install-tensorflow-gpu-2-0-f4e215438199). However there is now a `keras-gpu` metapackage available on Anaconda which apparently doesn't require installing CUDA and cuDNN libraries beforehand (mine were already installed anyway).

This is what worked for me to create a dedicated environment named `keras_gpu`:

```
# need to downgrade from tensorflow 2.1 for my particular setup
conda create --name keras_gpu keras-gpu=2.3.1 tensorflow-gpu=2.0
```

To add on @johncasey 's answer but for **TensorFlow 2.0**, adding this block works for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

# adjust values to your needs
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 1 , 'CPU': 8} )
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) 
K.set_session(sess)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840437/8876619) solved the `set_session` error I got: you need to use the keras backend from the tensorflow path instead of keras itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using Tensorflow 2.5, building on @MonkeyBack's answer:

```
conda create --name keras_gpu keras-gpu tensorflow-gpu

# should show GPU is available
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print('GPUs Available:', tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

See if your script is running GPU in Task manager. If not, suspect your CUDA version is right one for the tensorflow version you are using, as the other answers suggested already.

Additionally, a proper CUDA DNN library for the CUDA version is required to run GPU with tensorflow. Download/extract it from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) and put the DLL (e.g., cudnn64_7.dll) into CUDA bin folder (e.g., C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin).