# GCP GPU is not detected in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-compute-engine, nvidia

I'm running the UNet Keras model on a GCP instance with one NVIDIA Tesla P4GPU. But it does not detect the GPU. Instead it runs on the CPU. p.s. I installed drivers & tensorflow-gpu buy it wont work. How to fix this issue?

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (instance-1): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Comment: The error message contains your answer, is the nvidia kernel driver loaded?

Comment: Also you need a version of Tensorflow that support GPU. [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662253/can-i-run-keras-model-on-gpu)

Comment: How to find the nvidia kernal drivers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first install the driver. [Follow this instruction](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-grid-drivers)