# How to implement rescaling in custom DataGenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-generation, image-preprocessing

I created a custom `DataGenerator`by using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`:(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence).
This is the customized `DataGenerator`:

```
# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x*1/255
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (64, 128))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

`x_set` is a list of paths to my images and `y_set` are the associated classes.
I now would like to add a function to rescale every pixel of an image by multiplyig it with `rescale = 1./255` as in `ImageDataGenerator` class: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#ImageDataGenerator%20class

When I apply this code with the `model.fit_generator`:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 128,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 128,
                    epochs = 10)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-571a868b2d2a> in <module>()
      3                     steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 128,
      4                     validation_steps = num_val_samples // 128,
----> 5                     epochs = 10)

8 frames
<ipython-input-54-d98c3b0c7c56> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     15         self.batch_size]
     16         batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
---> 17         batch_x = batch_x*1/255
     18         batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
     19         self.batch_size]

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U77'), dtype('<U77')) -> dtype('<U77')
```

How do I have to modify my code?

Comment: batch_x * 1./255 ?

Comment: Where do I have to implement this code?

Comment: where you define batch_x or in the line below batch_x = batch_x*1/255

Comment: Then I get: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: to do this batch_x must be an array

Comment: I edited my question. I not get a `UFuncTypeError`...

Comment: pay attention where you apply imread... you have to read (in order to have array) before to apply rescale

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to programming and also after thinking about this, I do not get it correctly....

Comment: so without rescaling your generator works? correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (64, 128)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. However, it's really slow and I don't know. But it already was slow before... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612518/training-on-gpu-much-slower-than-on-cpu-why-and-how-to-speed-it-up/62621649?noredirect=1#comment110772351_62621649