# Keras 'set_session' not available for Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Attempting to do the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from keras import backend as K

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
```

When I run this in Google Colab I get:

```
RuntimeError: `set_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You could switch to TensorFlow 1.x in colab

Answer (score 16):

try using the keras backend from the tensorflow path. Your code gives me an error, but this works for me.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
```