# How can I use a GPU with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My problem is that I am trying to train a convolution neural network with Keras in google colab that is able to distinguish between dogs and cats, but at the time of passing to the training phase my model takes a long time to train and I wanted to know how I can use the GPU in the right way in order to make the training time take less time.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/files/dataset_CNN/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/files/dataset_CNN/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):#I tried to put this part that I found by researching on the internet 
  
  classifier = Sequential()
  classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
  classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
  classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
  classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
  classifier.add(Flatten())
  classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
  classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
  classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
  classifier.fit(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)
```

Previously, I did not put this part of the code "with tf.device('/device:GPU:0')", I saw this part of the code in an example on the internet, but it is still slow when training. I already checked the Available GPUs using:

```
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
```

Comment: Have you configured Colab's runtime to use a GPU? by default, colab is launching a CPU instance. Go to runtime > change runtime type > Hardware accelerator and switch to GPU.

Comment: Also, maybe it is better to use `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` instead of device name since in some system you may not get "GPU:0", but some other device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run Keras model on gpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662253/can-i-run-keras-model-on-gpu)

Comment: I switched from CPU to GPU usage on Google colab, and yes I entered that forum [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662253/can-i-run-keras-model-on-gpu) and had tried, but anyway it is slow in the training phase.

Comment: What does "slow" mean, GPUs are not a magic bullet that will make your code faster.

Answer (score 0):

**To Select GPU in Google Colab -**
Select Edit - Notebook Setting - Hardware accelerator - GPU - Save

[ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) is not recommended for new code. Instead you can use these augmentation features directly through [layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers) in model training as below:

```
classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
#data augmention layers
  layers.Resizing(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
  layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  layers.RandomZoom(0.1),
#model building layers
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'),
  layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
```

Also, you should use [image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) to import the images dataset which generates a `tf.data.Dataset` from image files in a directory. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/becc9043f6ef2210f62691e8330ca8da/75098116.ipynb) of replicated code.

**Note:**
fit() automatically calculates Steps_per_epoch from the training set as per batch_size.
`Steps_per_epoch = len(training_dataset)//batch_size`