# How can I check whether I use CPU or GPU in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I've read that

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ''
```

takes care that tensorflow will run on CPU and that

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'
```

takes care that tensorflow will run on GPU 0.

How can I check, which device is used?

The code

```
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

shows only the result

```
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

and no used device etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if tensorflow is using gpu acceleration from inside python shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by turning on the tensorflow logging statements.  There's a few ways to do this.  You can do it with a bash environment variable with..

```
export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=1
```

or from within your code with..

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

On my system I get something like...

> Device mapping: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 ->
>   device: XLA_CPU device
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 -> device: XLA_GPU
>   device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0,
>   name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute
>   capability: 5.2 MatMul: (MatMul):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 a: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 b: (Const):
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 [[22. 28.]  [49. 64.]]

Comment: I use spyder and I noticed that the output from "print(sess.run(c))" is different to the output when I use the Python console, which is similar to the description in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu. Why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with spyder but it must be doing something that's suppressing the python logging.  A quick search showed a few posts on this such as.. https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2572.  You'll have to google and read through the posts if you want to figure fix the log suppression issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are differences between Python and IPython. IPython is the used Kernel in Spyder. So I'm guessing that's the reason for those differing outputs.