# Inference on GPU with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make predictions with Keras using my RTX 2060 Super. For some reason, it appears to be running on my CPU instead.

Here's the test script I was using for debugging:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense


def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(6, 7, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def test_gpu():
    model = get_model()
    arg = np.random.rand(10000, 6, 7, 3)
    with tf.device('gpu'):
        for i in range(10000):
            print(i)
            model.predict(arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()
    tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
    test_gpu()
```

Here's the result that was printed to the console:

```
2020-07-04 16:02:53.476342: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.750958: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.829844: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:07:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.71GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-07-04 16:02:54.829996: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.833612: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.836233: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.837132: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.840536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.842135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.847975: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.848397: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-07-04 16:02:54.855989: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-04 16:02:54.862690: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x279fb82e950 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-04 16:02:54.862816: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863172: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:07:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.71GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863317: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863390: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863463: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863531: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863599: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863668: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.863737: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:54.864148: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.380931: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-07-04 16:02:55.381015: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-07-04 16:02:55.381059: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2020-07-04 16:02:55.381623: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6650 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-07-04 16:02:55.383791: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x279ab93e810 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-04 16:02:55.383895: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-07-04 16:02:55.385370: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RandomUniform in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.585261: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op Sub in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.585707: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op Mul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.585832: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op Add in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.586031: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.586161: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarIsInitializedOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.586336: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op LogicalNot in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.586529: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op Assert in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.586907: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.587688: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.588197: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.595362: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.603863: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.605481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.611149: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.616445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.617115: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.623924: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.636035: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RangeDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.636340: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.644954: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op MapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.645358: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op PrefetchDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.653283: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op FlatMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.653830: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op TensorDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.653992: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.654245: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ZipDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.657661: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ParallelMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.658464: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ModelDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.658648: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op AnonymousIteratorV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.658798: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op MakeIterator in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
iterator: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
iterator_1: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_conv2d_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_conv2d_1_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_conv2d_1_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_dense_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_dense_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_dense_1_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_dense_1_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_dense_2_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential_dense_2_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
IteratorGetNext: (IteratorGetNext): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.721249: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op __inference_predict_function_248 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722140: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/colocation_graph.cc:256] Ignoring device specification /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 for node 'IteratorGetNext' because the input edge from 'iterator' is a reference connection and already has a device field set to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] iterator: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722471: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] iterator_1: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722583: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_conv2d_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722710: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_conv2d_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_conv2d_1_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.722981: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_conv2d_1_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723118: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_dense_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723245: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_dense_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723378: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_dense_1_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723514: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_dense_1_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723643: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_dense_2_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723780: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential_dense_2_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.723913: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] IteratorGetNext: (IteratorGetNext): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724172: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724355: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724483: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724589: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724729: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.724882: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.725008: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.725137: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.731809: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/conv2d_1/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/flatten/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_1/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_1/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_1/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_2/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/dense_2/Tanh: (Tanh): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Identity: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
identity_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/flatten/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732008: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/flatten/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732143: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732276: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732406: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732537: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732657: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732794: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_1/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.732937: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_1/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733070: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733199: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_1/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733455: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733580: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_2/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733697: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733826: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.733939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/dense_2/Tanh: (Tanh): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.734039: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] Identity: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.734141: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] identity_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.734240: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.734339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] sequential/flatten/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:55.745329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:56.011439: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-07-04 16:02:57.154757: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
1
2020-07-04 16:02:57.354381: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ConcatV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.355353: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op DeleteIterator in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.357613: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RangeDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.357817: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.361556: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op MapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.362044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op PrefetchDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.369283: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op FlatMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.369687: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op TensorDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.369839: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.369993: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ZipDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.373118: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ParallelMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.373590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ModelDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2
2020-07-04 16:02:57.516787: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RangeDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.516987: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.520518: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op MapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.520843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op PrefetchDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.528061: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op FlatMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.528482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op TensorDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.528642: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op RepeatDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.528802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ZipDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.531905: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ParallelMapDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2020-07-04 16:02:57.532347: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:501] Executing op ModelDataset in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
3
```

And here's a screenshot showing my CPU and GPU utilization in Task Manager:

[image: Task Manager Screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Its a common misconception that you can determine if GPU is being used by looking at the task manager, it is not true. There is nothing here showing that GPU is NOT being used.

Comment: If you look at the tensorflow logs output I pasted, you can see that the majority of the operations are being done on the CPU, not the graphics card.

Comment: Yes, and that is not abnormal at all, not all operations can run on the GPU. Your model is really too tiny to put load in the GPU.

Comment: Turns out I WAS running on the GPU. I switched to using the CPU and it was much slower. I guess I just had unrealistic expectations for the speed and GPU utilization %. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary the points mentioned in the `Comments Section` here (`Answer Section`) and also providing the Code to check if `Tensorflow` is using `GPU` below, **for the benefit of the Community**.

We shouldn't use **`Task Manager`** to check if `GPU` is being used by `Tensorflow`.

Instead, we can use the code mentioned below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

If `Tensorflow` uses `GPU`, the Output of the above code will be:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0
True
```

You can also run the below code to know all the Devices being used by Tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Output of the above code when run with Runtime as GPU in Google Colab is shown below:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 1364469592146627999
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 1949236974972245157
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 7931601386541220977
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 14648777152
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 15267718363411873827
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.5"
]
```

You can also use the command, `nvidia-smi`.

For more information, please refer this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell).