# On a GPU-enabled computer, will tensorflow array operations be carried out on GPU automatically?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensor

Suppose we run the following code on a GPU-enabled computer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print ("results")
id= tf.eye(2,2)
x= tf.matmul(id,id)  #line 4
print (x)
```

Will line #line 4 be executed on GPU automatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55608481/8143158

Comment: In your link, "tf.test.is_gpu_available" asks if GPU is available. It does not mean GPU will be necessarily be used for tensor calculation I guess

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you mean "tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()" means the code runs on GPU?

Comment: TF defaults to gpu when available. You can also check variables where its executed by `x.device`.